# openframeworks, addons, and mavericks on osx

Tags: c++, macos, osx-mavericks, add-on, openframeworks

I had developed an app in openframeworks for OSX Mountain Lion using the addons ofxUI, ofxFFT, and ofxXmlSettings.

It worked beautifully. But recently I switched over to OSX 10.9 and now my code still compiles but errors immediately upon running.

```
2014-03-23 19:33:24.489 etaBasement_debug[47594:507] -[__NSCFError _cocoaErrorStringWithKind:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b61a060
```

I can't really find what I need on Google. If anyone knows how to fix this issue or if I need to give more information, please let me know.

Comment: What version of openFrameworks and the other addons are you using?  Is your code / project online anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the version but I think 0.8.0?
Code at https://github.com/jwbowler/etaBasement